# UIScope Bar doesn't show items (if no Searchtext is submitted)

Tags: ios

i have a Searchbar with a Scopebar in my RootViewController. If I am searching for the items it's working very fine, also if I searching in a Scope Range. **But how is it possible to show Scope Results, if no Searchtext was given from the User?**

A Code Sample would be very fine.

Here is the Code which filter after the User set Text into the Seachbar.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
[self.filteredContent removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.

    for (test *new in tabelle)
    {

        //cat1
        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"cat1"] && [new.Location isEqualToString:@"cat1"])
        {
            NSComparisonResult result = [new.TText compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

            if (result == NSOrderedSame)
            {
                [self.filteredContent addObject:new];
            }    
        }

        //cat2
       if ([scope isEqualToString:@"cat2"] && [new.Location isEqualToString:@"cat2"])  
        {
            NSComparisonResult result = [new.TText compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

            if (result == NSOrderedSame)
            {
                [self.filteredContent addObject:new];
            }
        }

        //all
        if ([scope isEqualToString:@"Alle"])  
        {   
            NSComparisonResult result = [new.TText compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

            if (result == NSOrderedSame)
            {
                [self.filteredContent addObject:new];
            } 
        }
    } 
}
```

I want results without any typed letter in the Searchbar

Like this image but without the typed in letter: http://edumobile.org/iphone/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/search.jpg

Comment: No Database Expert here? I don't found a Solution yet.

Comment: Does really nobody know how I can filter with only a Scopebar? Wow, that make me sad...

Comment: Ok, I will ask on another Forum.